# GroupBy Chart in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, chart-web-part

I have below data in List, I have created a chart where x axis=Loc, y axis=% Done. Now on x axis i want to display data for all quarter for one Loc together. I have tried using groupby on Quarter but it does not display correct chart. Please help.

```
Quarter Loc Done
1st     Nah 0
1st     Chu 51
2nd     Bee 17
3rd     Bee 51
4th     Bee 17
1st     Cap 17
2nd     Cap 0
3rd     Cap 17
4th     Cap 51
2nd     Ber 85
3rd     Ber 100
1st     Acu 0
1st     Alb 100
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried - why isn't the chart correct?